# ASP.NET - __doPostBack is not defined error from DataList ItemCommand event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net-4.0, datalist

I am using a DataList for custom paging implementation and the button click is working locally but after deploying it in my godaddy server the button click showing a __doPostBack is not defined error

The DataList code is in the **Usercontrol**

```
           <asp:DataList CellPadding="1"                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" ID="dlPager"                       onitemcommand="dlPager_ItemCommand">
             <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:LinkButton Enabled='<%#Eval("Enabled") %>' 
                       runat="server" ID="lnkPageNo" 
                       Text='<%#Eval("Text") %>' 
                       CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Value") %>' 
                       CommandName="PageNo" 
                       BorderStyle="Solid" 
                       BorderWidth="2px" 
                       Font-Bold="True" 
                       Font-Size="Medium" 
                       ForeColor="White" 
                       BackColor="#0066FF" 
                       BorderColor="#66FF33"   
                       Height="20px" 
                       CausesValidation="False">
                   </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate></asp:DataList>
```

And the View Source of the page shows,

```
  <table id="ctl00_cphBody_ctl00_dlPager" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" CausesValidation="False" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <td>
                   <input type="button" name="ctl00$cphBody$ctl00$dlPager$ctl00$lnkPageNo" value="1" id="ctl00_cphBody_ctl00_dlPager_ctl00_lnkPageNo" disabled="disabled" style="color:White;background-color:#0066FF;border-color:#66FF33;border-width:2px;border-style:Solid;font-size:Medium;font-weight:bold;height:20px;" />
            </td><td>
                   <input type="button" name="ctl00$cphBody$ctl00$dlPager$ctl01$lnkPageNo" value="2" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphBody$ctl00$dlPager$ctl01$lnkPageNo&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="ctl00_cphBody_ctl00_dlPager_ctl01_lnkPageNo" style="color:White;background-color:#0066FF;border-color:#66FF33;border-width:2px;border-style:Solid;font-size:Medium;font-weight:bold;height:20px;" />
            </td><td>
                   <input type="button" name="ctl00$cphBody$ctl00$dlPager$ctl02$lnkPageNo" value="3" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphBody$ctl00$dlPager$ctl02$lnkPageNo&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="ctl00_cphBody_ctl00_dlPager_ctl02_lnkPageNo" style="color:White;background-color:#0066FF;border-color:#66FF33;border-width:2px;border-style:Solid;font-size:Medium;font-weight:bold;height:20px;" />
            </td>
</tr>
```

User control code behind

```
protected void dlPager_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "PageNo")
    {
        GetData(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
    }
}
```

And the page load is

```
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {         
        GetData(1);  
    }
```

I tried the solution mentioned in other similar threads but none worked.

I can see the doPostback scipt is already present in the viewsource of the page. I am using VS 2010

Comment: So were have you defined __doPostBack ??

Comment: I didn't specify it in the usercontrol explicitly. I tried the code Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty); inside the UserControl's PageLoad event  but didn't work.

Comment: What is the normal way to define doPostBack from usercontrol?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);` to the link button's `OnClick` event. So you have to do it in `dlPager_ItemDataBound`, where you can find the `LinkButton` from `e.Item.FindControl`. Your code might look like this:

```
protected void dlPager_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    var lb = e.Item.FindControl("lnkPageNo") as LinkButton;
    if (lb != null)
    {
        lb.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you have this in your markup:  `OnItemDataBound="dlPager_ItemDataBound" `. The code sample above is tested and itis working.

Comment: I have OnItemDataBound="dlPager_ItemDataBound" markup in place but not sure why this is not working

Comment: Did it hit the method? Try to set a break point in `var lb = ...`

Comment: Yes it does hit on the method and the assignments are happening. Please share if you have any sample code which is in working condition.

Comment: Is the usercontrol inside any type of ajax control, like UpdatPanel?

Comment: You can download my test project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0RUpZcHNxYjF0eTg/edit?usp=sharing), if it helps.

Comment: It is not using any ajax

Comment: Strange, I can see the `_doPostBack`  inside `script` tag rendered each time in my test!

Comment: Yes in your code its working but not sure the issue with my code. One more point I am using this inside the BlogEngine.Net's version 2.8

Comment: Hmmm... maybe that is your issue. Is it okay to share the code?